# Active record foreign key primary key issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

let's say I have two tables, they are linked by custom columns:

```
table1s
  id varchar
  user_id varchar

table2s
  id varchar
  linked_user_id varchar
```

now, I try to make a relationship in the Ruby code

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "id"

    has_many :table2s, primary_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :table1
end

class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "id"

    belongs_to :table1, foreign_key: :linked_user_id, inverse_of: :table2s
end
```

now, when I try to make a SQL query, it uses for some reason `id` column instead of the specified `user_id`

```
Table2.select('table2s.*')
          .joins(:table1)
          .where('table1s.id = ?', 323235)
```

the generated SQL looks like below:

```
SELECT table2s.*
FROM table2s
INNER JOIN table1s ON table1s.id = table2s.linked_user_id
WHERE table1s.id = 323235
```

I was expecting it to be `user_id` not the `id`:

```
SELECT table2s.*
FROM table2s
INNER JOIN table1s ON table1s.user_id = table2s.linked_user_id
WHERE table1s.id = 323235
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a custom relationship where the keys differ from the `primary_key` for the class (table) then you need to add both `foreign_key` and `primary_key` to the relationship in order for the join to work correctly. e.g.

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "id"

    has_many :table2s, primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :linked_user_id, inverse_of: :table1
end

class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "id"

    belongs_to :table1, primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :linked_user_id, inverse_of: :table2s
end
```

`belongs_to`
From the [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

> :primary_key
> Specify the method that returns the primary key of associated object used for the association. By default this is id.

`has_many` From the [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

> :foreign_key Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to :favorite_person, class_name: "Person" will use a foreign key of “favorite_person_id”.